# get an array to print on two lines but its going on one

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to teach myself html n javascript I dont think I'm doing too badly however I am trying to get an array to print on two lines but its going on one like below.

my javascript looks like this:

```
var Abc = function(foo, bar) {
this.foo=foo;
this.bar=bar;
}

var def = new Abc("foo", ["foo", "bar"]);
var ghj = new Abc("bar", "foo");
var klm = [def, ghj];

for(var i = 0; i < klm.length; i++) {
    var testPara = document.createElement("p");
    var testNode = document.createTextNode(klm[i].foo);
    testPara.appendChild(testNode);
    document.getElementById(foobar).appendChild(testPara);

    var testPara1 = document.createElement("p");
    var testNode1 = document.createTextNode(klm[i].foo);
    testPara.appendChild(testNode);
    document.getElementById(foobar).appendChild(testPara1);
}
```

my html is like this:

```
<section id="foobar"></section>
```

what I want it to print out on the page is

foo

foo

bar

bar

foo

but what I am getting is:

foo

foo,bar

bar

foo

I tried putting a nested for loop to split them up but it just printed out the same thing about 20 times before moving on

Also do I have to put the instances of the object into an array to get this to work or is there another simpler way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `var def = new Abc("foo", ["foo", "bar"]);` defines creates an object like this:

```
def: {
    foo: "foo",
    bar: ["foo", "bar"]
}
```

If you want it to print the contents of `def.bar` on separate lines, then either:

- Split the `bar` part of `def` to be one string instead of an array; or
- Modify your function to understand that bar can be an array of strings.